# jQuery .load() html content and execute script

Tags: jquery, load, fancybox, execute

I have the following functions in my document

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery('body').on('click', 'a.menu', function () { 
        var target = jQuery(this).attr('href');
    jQuery('#container').load(target+' #content');
        return false;
    });

$("a.group").fancybox();

});
```

The first one replaces the container with the href of the menu link.
The corresponding subpages are actually plain divs but could be complete html (if necessary).

The second one calls a fancybox gallery on the selected elements.

How do i get this `$("a.group").fancybox()` to be executed, when the subpages are loaded?

Many thx in advance,
mart05

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) has a callback function. so execute the fancybox in this:

```
jQuery('#container').load(target+' #content', function() {
              $("a.group").fancybox();
          });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the complete callback feature in [.loads](http://api.jquery.com/load/).

```
jQuery('#container').load(target+' #content', function(){
    // this will run when .load has completed loading content
    $("a.group").fancybox();
});
```